# How zsh/sh/bash check signal SIGTTIN for command "cat &" launched from a c++ program

Tags: c++, bash, signals

I can't understand *How the terminal knows if a binary used `stdin` in background mode*?

I have a C++ program that must run commands like `/bin/cat` in the background, but I DONT get the error message:

> `cat` is stopped because it used `stdin` and got `SIGTTIN`

Comment: Why is this question tagged with c++ and how is it related to programming?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Just removed it - had to somehow vet an edit first.

Comment: The problem is that at this point, `cat` is waiting for input on `stdin`, but you've not given it an input file (via `< in` or a pipe) and it's not connected to your terminal as `stdin`, so it got the signal `SIGTTIN` as soon as it tried to read from `stdin`. The terminal gets notified of this because interactive terminals have job control enabled by default, and so when they background job got suspended waiting in input from `stdin`, the message popped up.

Comment: @PaulEvans I used C++ tag because at this moment I try create an app. This app must run /bin/cat in background. Give my tag back!

Comment: Fixed the question so the c++ connection is clear. @ИгорьИванов, please review my edit to make sure I didn't diverge from your actual meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So. After two days trying and crying now I solve this problem. If you want give your child process SIGTTIN you should call setpgid() in parent process.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that at this point, `cat` is waiting for input on `stdin`, but you've not given it an input file (via `< in` or via a pipe like `echo foo | cat &`) and it's not connected to your terminal as `stdin` since you put it in the background, so it got the signal `SIGTTIN` as soon as it tried to read from `stdin`. The terminal gets notified of this because interactive terminals have job control enabled by default, and so when the background job got suspended waiting in input from `stdin`, the message popped up.

If you're trying to open `cat` in the background from a C++ program, you have to make sure to connect its `stdin` in the call when you're launching the `cat` process: give it a file, a pipe, or connect it to a file handle in your own program.

Comment: I dont have a problem with this information. I just want to know How it works in code C++

Comment: just added a note about c++ at the bottom. Does that help?

Comment: no. sorry, you dont understand me. if I run /bin/cat in my app - its work normally. but I wont to handle an error like in a terminal

Comment: Ah, OK. I think I get it now, sorry for mangling the question, and I'm glad you fixed it. This is much deeper a question than I realized. I put you C++ tag back on, by the way, and I would say this is a C++ signals question, but not really a bash one. Now that I get your question, it seems like you need bash-style job control within C++, and I have no idea how to do that. I hope someone else can help. You might want to edit your question to make it more directly to that point, something like "I would like to monitor child processes in C++ in a way similar to what bash does".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to use a [`std::signal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal), something like:

```
void signal_handler(int signal)
{
    std::cout << "Received SIGTTIN signal\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::signal(SIGTTIN, signal_handler);
    ...
}
```